# NetSuite Advanced PDF condition to display text

Tags: pdf, netsuite

I am trying to design a custom invoice for my company and I am stuck on a couple of issues.
I want to have a text line disclaimer appear only when the invoice is for an export inside of EU (my company is based in EU, so the line would have to display only for countries in EU other than my country);

I have very basic HTML skills however and I can't seem to figure out how the code should look like in order to set this up. Can anyone provide any insight on this?

Comment: The NetSuite help is pretty extensive for the basics. As well Advanced PDF Templates use FreeMarker which has documentation online. for example : https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_if.html

Answer (score 0):

I suggest one of the following approaches, #2 would be easier but #1 addresses your direct question of using the templates.

1. Create at least 2 [Custom Transaction Forms](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/10115), one for invoices within EU and one for outside of EU.  Create a [Custom Transaction Body Field](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/10089/kw/10089) (text field with a default value) to hold the EU disclaimer, and display it on Form 1.  If needed, create a [Custom Advanced PDF/HTML Template](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/26494) to position all the fields (including disclaimer) the way you want it, and attach it to Form 1. *You actually don't need to create the custom field.  the Custom Advanced PDF/HTML Template allows you to add free text.
2. Create a [Description Item](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/28177) to hold the disclaimer text.  That item can be manually added to all invoices, or you can do some programming to add the item to invoices.  For the programming you can achieve this using NetSuite (javascript based) SuiteScript.  You can create a [beforeSubmit User Event Script](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/44546) to determine if disclaimer is needed and add one as the last line.  Or a [saveRecord Client Script](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/44560) to determine if disclaimer is needed, if one is present, and not allow user to save the record until adding one.